# How to add values of a variable for specific turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I want to add the values of a variable ( let's say transportation cost) for specific turtles which are in a group. The transportation cost depends on the distance between a specific patch and the location assigned to the turtle. As the value of the said cost is different for each turtle, I want to sum the total cost for turtle which are in a group. To clarify, let's suppose there are 7 turtles in total and only 4 are in a group.

The values of transportation cost of each turtle is assigned as tcost.

`to calculate-ttcost 
      set ttcost 0
      let cnt 0
      ask turtles  [
          if in-group? [
             set ttcost (tcost + tcost)
              set cnt cnt + 1
   ]
]
end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the correction of one typo, the code you have should work, assuming that `tcost` is declared as a `turtles-own` variable with that turtle's transportation cost (or a reporter that gives the transportation cost for the turtle that calls it), and assuming that those turtles that are in the group in which you are interested have their turtles-own variable `in-group?` set to true. The typo is in the line

```
set ttcost (tcost + tcost)
```

which should be

```
set ttcost (ttcost + tcost)
```

But there is a more straight-forward coding that will accomplish the same task.

```
let cnt count turtles with [in-group?]
let ttcost sum [tcost] of turtles with [in-group?]
```

`with` limits the set of turtles to those for which `in-group` is true. `of` creates a list of the values of `tcost` for each of those turtles, which can then be summed up.